# SharePoint 2013 people search hover panel customisation

Tags: search, people-search

We have a SharePoint 2013 intranet portal. When I search for a Employee in people search (let's say I'm searching for HR Manager) the people search hover panel displays the documents authored by that person as shown below.

Now staff's are complaining that the document displayed on the hover panel is confidential and they should'nt want others to view those documents.

What is the best approach to remove the "Authored Documents" (modifying the hover panel template JS file) or exclude the document from hover panel results.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the documents are secured they will not appear to users who do not have access. If you cannot get that message across to your users you can cripple this feature by finding the section of the ItemPerson_HoverPanel and remove the code that performs that function.

Comment: The way I understand is the document should have unique permission so that the hover panel cannot display that document. Any idea about the logic used by hover panel to display the documents?

Comment: It is using a search query. If the doc is not secure then everyone can see it, just like in search. Are they concerned that they can see documents in the everything search??